# How can I resolve a duplicate key that doesn't exist in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

Why does this duplicate key raise an error?

```
UPDATE myTable SET status = 1 WHERE status != 1 AND age IN (1,2,3);
#Duplicate entry '2015-02-20-1-1' for key 'date_status_id' 0.82 secs
```

But none exist:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `date` = '2015-02-20' AND `status` = 1 AND `age` = 1;
#No results
```

`date_status_age` `(date, status, age)` is the only `UNIQUE` index.

Here's the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_stats` (
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `date_status_age` (`date`,`status`,`age`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: What's the index definition?

Comment: `date_status_id` is the only `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: That must be three fields in your key.

Comment: Give us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output of this table.

Comment: Sorry `date_status_id` `(date, status, id)` is the only `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: See update for create table.

Comment: Unrelated -- but you don't need the `date_status_multi` index, it's just duplicating what `date_status_id` already gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UNIQUE index is defined as follows:

```
date_status_id (date, status, id)
```

and you don't have any record with status = 1:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `date` = '2015-02-20' AND `status` = 1 AND `id` = 1;
```

but you might have more records with status != 1:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `date` = '2015-02-20' AND `status` != 1 AND `id` = 1;
```

I believe that this query will return more than one record, and those multiple records will be all updated to status = 1, and that causes the error.

The problem here is that you have defined ID as AUTO_INCREMENT, but since there's no UNIQUE index associated to it so you can have multiple rows with the same ID.

Comment: `id` field is defined as primary key -- that makes it automatically unique.

Comment: Ah ha! That's totally it. Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan you're welcome... but are you sure you defined ID as a primary key `PRIMARY KEY (`id`)` ? As Alex suggested, that should make id unique...

Comment: No, Alex is correct, my example showed this, but it isn't like that in reality. Apologies to all for the confusing example. I didn't count on the unique primary key.